# No output on the console

Tags: eclipse, plugins, console

my problem is about eclipse plugin. I wrote a plugin for my eclipse. As a project it works fine, it shows the required dialog boxes and required output on the console. When I put my plugin into eclipse, it doesnt show any output on the console, it just show dialog boxes. What should I do to fix this issue.

Comment: How are you launching Eclipse when your plug-in has been installed? Do you see a console or terminal window?

Comment: I didnt get your question, when I launch the plugin from project it shows a simple eclipse screen and there is just a task screen at bottom. But when I click from the installed plugin (it stands as menu item) there is nothing happening in the console just the dialog boxes are coming (like your process is done successfully).

Answer (score 0):

Console output using calls like `System.out.println` only works when you are testing your plugin from with Eclipse.

When you install a plugin into Eclipse `System.out.println` output is **not** shown in the Eclipse console. To write to a Console the plugin must use the Eclipse Console APIs. See [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F) for more details.